# Why doesn't Halley's method give the exact root for quadratic functions but does for linear functions?

Tags: numerical-methods

I just finished working through the proof of Halley's method using a second order Taylor expansion. I have also heard that the method does not produce an exact solution for quadratic functions but does for linear functions. I was hoping to get some feedback on why this is. Maybe a general proof.

Answer (score 2):

Halley's method as originally used by Halley used the exact solution of the up to quadratic terms, thus would solve a quadratic equation correctly in one step.

The "modern" version of Halley's method uses a hyperbolic approximation of the function, one could say the 1/1 Padé approximant and thus gets also the root as rational expression in the function value and derivatives. This will always leave an error term if the equation to be solved is quadratic.

The order of both variants is of course 3. The Newton fractals also look quite different, parabolic looks more "geometric" and "hyperbolic" has finer-scaled fractal edges. The polynomial is $x^5+3x^3-5x^2-1$.

| parabolic Halley | hyperbolic Halley |
| --- | --- |
| [image: parhalley] | [image: hyphalley] |

Comment: Very nice answer, for sure